# Como fazer um migração Code First sem excluir dados do atributo da tabela?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, code-first

Preciso alterar o nome do atributo de **Peso** para **PesoProduto**, esse é o código que é gerado após executar o comando **add-migration**:

```
namespace Web.Dominio.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class alterar_Peso_para_PesoProduto_em_Produto : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Produto", "PesoProduto", c => c.Decimal(precision: 18, scale: 2));
            DropColumn("dbo.Produto", "Peso");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Produto", "Peso", c => c.Decimal(precision: 18, scale: 2));
            DropColumn("dbo.Produto", "PesoProduto");
        }
    }
}
```

o problema é que os dados da coluna **é deletado** e eu não quero deletar os dados eu quero alterar somente o nome do atributo da tabela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce vai precisar editar manualmente a migration gerada, substituindo `Add` e `Drop` por `Rename`:

```
public override void Up()
{
    //AddColumn("dbo.Produto", "PesoProduto", c => c.Decimal(precision: 18, scale: 2));
    //DropColumn("dbo.Produto", "Peso");

    // Vira
    RenameColumn("dbo.[Produtos]", "Peso", "PesoProduto");
}

public override void Down()
{
    //AddColumn("dbo.Produto", "Peso", c => c.Decimal(precision: 18, scale: 2));
    //DropColumn("dbo.Produto", "PesoProduto");

    RenameColumn("dbo.[Produtos]", "PesoProduto", "Peso");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No método `Up` e `Down`, limpe o código e coloque [`RenameColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.renamecolumn(v=vs.113).aspx), com os paramentos em sequencia no método `Up`:

> - `Nome da tabela`
> - `Nome atual do campo da tabela`
> - `Novo nome para o campo da tabela`

No exemplo abaixo para o seu problema:

```
public partial class alter_coluna_peso_pesoproduto : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {           
        RenameColumn("dbo.Produto", "Peso", "PesoProduto");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {

    }
}
```

***Referencias:***

- [DbMigration.RenameColumn Method (String, String, String, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.renamecolumn(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [Entity Framework Migrations renaming tables and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13297248/6797930)